# What coordinate system does a depth texture use?

Tags: opengl-es, coordinate-systems, depth-buffer, opengl-es-3.0

I have a depth texture and I would like to know in which coordinate system are the values stored inside the depth texture. Homogeneous coordinates, camera coordinates, world coordinates or model coordinates?

I also would like to know what values are stored in the depth texture and what do they mean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a value in range [`min`, `max`] where `min` is either `-1.0` or `0.0` and `max` is `1.0` though what you get from the texture might simply be an integer value which might need to be transformed (from 24-bit to 32-bit). If none confirms any of these you will need to test it yourself.

Anyway, these values `min` and `max` should represent the clipping planes so `min = near` and `max = far` due to the depth buffer optimisation. To get the true `Z` value from texture coordinate `ZT` then:

```
Z = near + ((far-near) * ((ZT-min)/(max-min)))
```

This `Z` then represents the distance from `(0,0,0)` from the user perspective this is the distance between object and the camera position.

Try looking for some [literature](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~colombar/html_openGL_tutorial/en/06depth_020.html).